# Upgrade multiple servers to 16.04 using Landscape LDS

Tags: upgrade, package-management, landscape, do-release-upgrade

We have roughly 10 systems running Ubuntu Server 14.04, one of which is running Landscape LDS 16 (whatever the latest version is).

What is the best way to go about upgrading all of these systems to the latest LTS release (16.04) in bulk? I realize 10 systems isn't a ton and I could do them manually in a reasonable amount of time, but I'm mostly curious for furthering my knowledge.

Surely in a large environment there is a better solution to upgrading between LTS releases than manually running `do-release-upgrade` on every system. I could run a custom command on each box to execute `do-release-upgrade`, but as far as retaining configuration files, accepting whatever prompts come up, etc, I feel there must be some "best practice" way to do this at scale.

Answer (score 2):

Landscape provides this functionality under the monicker of "Release Upgrades": if you select a set of systems, you should be prompted with options to kick off the [release upgrade process](https://help.landscape.canonical.com/ReleaseUpgrades).

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't address my question at all. In fact, I even mentioned in the OP that's we're using Landscape already.

Comment: Doh. That will teach me to read the full question.

Comment: There. I answered the right question this time ;-)